# A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit) 19.04

Tags: 19.04

Recentemente instalei o Ubuntu 19.04 e ao instalar o Driver da nVidia e reiniciar o PC obtive o seguinte erro.

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Recently I installed the Ubuntu 19.04 and when installed nVidia's Driver and reboot the machine, get the this error:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

Someone know's how to solve?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you tell us how you installed the Nvidia driver? You can [edit] your question to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an older Thinkpad T520 and getting the same thing on 19.04.
If I hard restart and then turn off WiFi I can usually get to the sign on panel.